# OpenVPN connects but can not connect to local network resources or browse internet

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I've managed to setup an OpenVPN server and can connect my client to the VPN however once connected I can not browse the internet or connect to any resources on the network.

I think the issue may be something to do with the routes that are being pushed and the fact that I'm using a bridged interface (br0).  I originally setup the bridged interface because I wanted to run some virtuals in KVM and now I've used br0 as the interface in the OpenVPN config but think I need to somehow bridge it to the TUN interface if that is possible or have I missed something else?

My /etc/network/interfaces:-

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

My /etc/ufw/before.rules:-

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to br0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

My OpenVPN server.conf:-

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Output of IP Route:-

```
default via 10.0.0.138 dev br0
10.0.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.112
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-e47e403dd1c1 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

* OpenVPN is not running in docker

This is ipconfog /all from the Windows client when connected to the VPN (no gateway would seem to be an issue)

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-5E-0C-75-B4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::954d:364c:745f:c2bc%19(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, 30 July 2018 1:04:44 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 30 July 2019 1:04:44 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.5
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318832478
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-00-A8-EA-28-80-23-0A-55-10
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 208.67.222.222
                                       208.67.220.220
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Please edit your post and show us `ip route` output.

Comment: @waltinator  Added `ip route` output

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work it out thanks to some other posts.  It appears my etc/ufw/before.rules had a mistake in the subnet; instead of /8 I've updated to /24 and all seems to be working well now!

In `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

Updated:-

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE``
```

To:-

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Thanks all for helping me with this